# Passing information through js files running on different HTML

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, google-chrome-extension, web-crawler

i'm building up a chrome extension which blocks ads from youtube, and it has a popup menu with the following style: [image: My popup menu]

Whenever i access this popup menu i have no problems using local storage to keep all the information from the radio buttons and the button, when i open the popup i send myself an alert() and it shows the right values of the variable.

however, because of the structure of these extensions, i'm messing with 2 htmls, one is the popup, and the other one is the Youtube HTML, whenever i try to access these informations using the local storage data, it always returns false (at least it's not returning null anymore, so i guess i'm on the right way"), and i just can't find a way to access this information variables on my other js script which manipulates the youtube html.

heres the popup html:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="pt-br">
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="main.css">
</head>
<body>
<div class="top-container">
    <img src="icon_48.png">
    <h2>Yazigi Ad Skipper</h2>
</div>
<div class="container">
<h3>Section of functionalities</h3>
<b>Skip video AD:</b>
<label>
    <input type="radio" name="option" value="after">
    After 5 seconds
</label>
<label>
    <input type="radio" name="option" value="instantly">
    Instantly&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
</label>
<br>
<b>Block banners and ad images:</b>
<label>
    <input type="radio" name="option1" value="activated">
    Activated&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
</label>
<label>
    <input type="radio" name="option1" value="deactivated">
    Deactivated
</label>
<button id="onoff">Turn off Ad Skipper</button>
</div>
<script src="popup.js" defer></script>
</body>
</html>
```

heres the popup js:

```
// popup.js

var AdSkipper;
var WaitVideoAd;
var closeBanner;

function initializeVariables() {
AdSkipper = localStorage.getItem('AdSkipper') === 'true';
WaitVideoAd = localStorage.getItem('WaitVideoAd') === 'true';
closeBanner = localStorage.getItem('closeBanner') === 'true';
}

// Initialize variables
initializeVariables();

// Function to update button text and localStorage
function updateAdSkipperButton() {
    let button = document.getElementById("onoff");
    if (AdSkipper) {
        button.innerText = 'Turn off Ad Skipper';
    } else {
        button.innerText = 'Turn on Ad Skipper';
    }
    localStorage.setItem('AdSkipper', AdSkipper);
}
// Event listener for the "Turn on/off Ad Skipper" button
document.getElementById("onoff").addEventListener("click", function () {
    AdSkipper = !AdSkipper;
    // Update localStorage after AdSkipper is changed
    localStorage.setItem('AdSkipper', AdSkipper);
    // Update button text
    updateAdSkipperButton();
});

// Event listener for the radio button with name "option"
document.querySelectorAll('input[name="option"]').forEach(function (radio) {
    radio.addEventListener("change", function () {
        WaitVideoAd = this.value === "after";
        localStorage.setItem('WaitVideoAd', WaitVideoAd);
    });
});

// Event listener for the radio button with name "option1"
document.querySelectorAll('input[name="option1"]').forEach(function (radio) {
    radio.addEventListener("change", function () {
        closeBanner = this.value === "activated";
        localStorage.setItem('closeBanner', closeBanner);
    });
});

// Initialize the button text based on the stored value
updateAdSkipperButton();

// Alerts after initializing variables
alert(AdSkipper);
alert(WaitVideoAd);
alert(closeBanner);
```

if needed, that's how i structured the manifest:

```
 "action": {
    "default_popup": "popup.html"
},
"content_scripts": [{
    "run_at": "document_start",
    "matches": ["*://*.youtube.com/*"],
    "js": ["script.js"]
}]
```

and that was my fair attempt to access the variables data from the main script file:

```
window.addEventListener('yt-page-data-updated', function () {
AdSkipper =   localStorage.getItem('AdSkipper') === 'true';
WaitVideoAd = localStorage.getItem('WaitVideoAd') === 'true';
closeBanner = localStorage.getItem('closeBanner') === 'true';
});
```

Comment: Don't use `localStorage` use [`chrome.storage.local` or `..sync`](https://developer.chrome.com/docs/extensions/reference/storage/)

Comment: The scope of `localStorage` is the domain, so it cannot be used for that purpose.

Comment: so the way to go is working with an API to storage the info? (my biggest fear